# Saving file to filesDir but goes to data/user

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider, internal-storage

After a process that i send an image through i save it in the internal storage and i keep the imageUri path to my Model.

```
val localUriName = "${server}_${clientMessageId}_${filename}"        context.openFileOutput(localUriName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
      it.write(compactFile.toByteArray())
 }


fileInformation.localUri = "${context.filesDir}${File.separator}$localUriName"
```

When debugging the code i see that the localUri has a value like "data/user/0/files/filename.jpg"

In some point in my Activity i want to display the image so i try to get the uri for the File with FileProvider and i get an Exception

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, File(it.localUri))
```

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.package.name/files/100_52_IMG-17f68c26802dc5306ac1c773be23e7f8-V.jpg
```

My file_provider_paths are the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />

    <external-files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />

    <external-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

So why i save it in the data/user but i retrieve it from the data/data??

Comment: "So why i save it in the data/user but i retrieve it from the data/data??" -- they are the same location, from your app's standpoint. "My file_provider_paths are the following" -- use unique values for `name`.

Comment: You mean that the problem is the same name="files" that i have in the paths xml?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that the problem is that i have same 'name' values in the file_provider_paths.xml. I changed them and it works fine!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="internal_files"
        path="." />

    <external-files-path
        name="external_path_files"
        path="." />

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```